# fatal error: genlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, compiler-errors, static-libraries

I try to compile this in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"

main()
{
int n1 , n2 , total ;

printf("1st Number : ") ;
n1 =GetInteger() ;
printf("2nd Number : ") ;
n2 = GetInteger() ;
total = n1 + n2 ;
printf("%d\t total is" , total);
}
```

but I get this error o1.c:2:20: fatal error: genlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Anyone knows how to fix it ? I dont know if it matters but my OS is Kali

Comment: replace `GetInteger()` with `fgets()` and `sscanf()` (or, maybe better, write your own `GetInteger()` with those other 2 functions). Also get rid of the local `#includes`.

Comment: What are those local libraries supposed to do? Where did you find data about them?

Comment: I think I will go with scanf

Comment: I found the piece of code in the : The art of science of c

Comment: honestly I don't know I am total new to c and I am reading The art of science of C .I think that are libraries from the book pfff I am really comfused right now

Comment: The error `o1.c:2:20: fatal error: genlib.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.` means.... well that the file `genlib.h` does not exist. Get some book or tutorial on C and come back here later.